# Backing up VMware Fusion virtual machines?

Tags: backup, vmware-fusion

Can I simply copy the virtual machine file to another directory while the VM is powered down?

This seems to work other than the fact that it changes the icon of the VM file to an exclamation mark in yellow triangle.

Does anyone have some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply copy the virtual machine directories to make a backup. Just remember you need to copy all the files (VMX is the VM configuration, VMDK are the virtual disk images).